# Passing string and variables into a directive attribute.

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to pass a dynamic query string into a directive that will filter the results that come back. So my code looks like this:

So say in my controller I have this:

```
var ctrlAs = this;
ctrlAs.location = "USA";
```

then in my html I have a directive:

```
<directive filter="location=ctrlAs.location">
```

THen in my directive i'm bringing in location like "=filter". I would expect the output in the directive to be "location=USA", but instead the output in the directive is just "USA".

Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: try this filter="lctrlAs.location"

Comment: I realized my mistake right after I posted. I needed filter="'location=' + ctrlAs.location"

Answer (score 1):

try like this.

OR change directive template like this

```
   template : '<div><span><label>location=</label>{{filter}}</span></div>'
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',[])
myApp.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            filter: '='
        },
        template : '<div><span>{{filter}}</span></div>',

      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {        
      }
    }
});
      

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.location = 'USA';
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        <directive  filter="'location='+location"  />
    </div>
</div>
```